# Java streaming audio via multicast

Tags: java, networking, audio, multicast

I would like to write a simple Java app that can stream audio from a .wav file to multiple clients which play the ingoing samples. Sadly, I don't work with Java often so I have no clue how to solve this problem with the classes I can use. (I want to use the standard classes only if possible)

My approach would be something like this:

**server setup**

```java
File source = new File(sourcePath);
AudioInputStream stream  = new AudioInputStream (source);
AudioFormat format = new AudioFormat (stream);

MulticastSocket socket = new MulticastSocket(port);
scoket.joinGroup(multicastAddress);
enter code here
```

**server running**

```java
// didn't thought about this very well yet
byte audioSamples[] = new byte[bufferSize * format.getFrameSize()];
// wavePos is the current position in the .wav File
stream.read(audioSamples, wavePos, bufferSize);

DatagramPacket audioBufferOut = new DatagramPacket(audioSamples, 
                                                   bufferSize, 
                                                   socket, 
                                                   port);
socket.send(audioBufferOut );
```

**client running**

I don't know how receiving multicast works right now but I imagine something like this.

```java
byte audioSamples[] = new byte[bufferSize * format.getFrameSize()];
DatagramPacket audioBufferIn = new DatagramPacket(audioSamples, bufferSize);
socket.receive(audioBufferIn);
// do some stuff with the new audio samples in the byte-Array
```

Question:
How do I use the new bytes I read through the socket? (= playing them)
How do I time the two processes? 
How should I tell the client what the audio format is? Is there a way to send a class instance (AudioFormat woudl be usefule).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you solve this question? If you do, I would appreciate any help.

Comment: I wouldn't like to answer my own question with code I'm not sure still works. I got the project to run somehow but I can't remember how it works and I'm quite sure that there are better ways to do this. 

If you want to have a look, here are client and server. I'm german so the comments are in german (Must have stopped commenting on german shortly after) 

www.wrodewald.de/others/AudioMulticastProject.zip

The important stuff is happening in the src path's in AudioMulticastClient and AudioMulticastServer

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.